# Postgres: How to prevent read with explicit lock?

Tags: postgresql

I have an app similar to chat roulette where users are randomly matched. I am doing this on the database level by matching two users with `user.looking == true`

However, this is vulnerable if user A is waiting and users B and C go on at the same time.

Is there a way to lock a record so that it can't be read when I make a query? Like if user B goes makes the `SELECT * FROM users WHERE looking=true` query first (which would return user A), I want the same query to return nothing for user C.

I was looking at this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html
but row level locks don't look like they work for reading?

> In addition to table-level locks, there are row-level locks, which can
>   be exclusive or shared locks. An exclusive row-level lock on a
>   specific row is automatically acquired when the row is updated or
>   deleted. The lock is held until the transaction commits or rolls back,
>   just like table-level locks. Row-level locks do not affect data
>   querying; they block only writers to the same row.

Basically I need a way to

1) look up a record

2) update it

without the risk of another thread finding that same record.

Comment: Just update it - it will be locked automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. if A B C do query at the same time, and you want only one can get the record like user.looking == true, just update the record, pg will actually do three steps here

- begin;
- update record
- commit;

Assuming A doing the update, B want update the record at the same time, B will block at the update record step. Looks like that A lock the record, in fact that MVCC block the update from B. Updating lock the table with ROW EXCLUSIVE lock, and ROW EXCLUSIVE do not block ROW EXCLUSIVE lock.

When A B update at the same time:

[image: example here1]

[image: example here2]